# Compare Voctor.y

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, vector

Hey i'm comparing 2 Vector.y's but it isnt working!

Here the code:

```
print(last.y + " == " + controller.transform.position.y);
if (last.y == controller.transform.position.y)
```

The print: 0,7999999 == 0,7999999

Comment: Please post more code rather than this small snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing floating point numbers. To get those exactly equal is hard. Unity only shows a limited amount of decimals in the editor. Try rounding the numbers. 
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Round.html

I.e.:

```
float randomNumber = 2.543686;

randomNumber = Mathf.Round(randomNumber * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

will return 2.54

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how precise you want you could also do:

```
// If absolute difference between last y and controller pos y is less than 0.0001
if (Mathf.abs(last.y - controller.transformer.position.y) < 0.0001f) {
// do something
}
```